# Struts2 customExceptionMappingInterceptor

Tags: java, exception, struts2, interceptor

I already searched here and on internet but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I would like to use my custom exception handler to intercept all the Java exceptions and to treat them in a specific way (I will set specific status to a response and then in the generic Ajax error: call they will be processed and JS dialog will be created with specific message).

So I created my action:

```
public class DefaultExceptionHandlerAction extends ExceptionMappingInterceptor  {

/** The class logger. */
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DefaultExceptionHandlerAction.class);

@Override
protected void publishException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

    LOGGER.error("Global Exception msg: "+ exceptionHolder.getException().getMessage(), exceptionHolder.getException());

    String message = "error msg for client";

    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(message);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException in printMessage : " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Beside this, in my struts.xml i have:

```
 <interceptor name="exception" class="com.travelsoft.orchestra.b2b.configuration.DefaultExceptionHandlerAction" />

 <interceptor-stack name="securedStack">
   <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
   <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
   <interceptor-ref name="login" />
 </interceptor-stack>

<global-results>
  <result name="exception">/defaultExceptionHandler.action</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
  <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

In one specific action, I forced null pointer exception directly in the code.
Of course, this action is using `securedStack` interceptor.

When this action is executed, I have undetermined loop.

javascript:

```
  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // all other errors
     var contentDialog = $("<div/>",{ "id":"contentDialog"});
     contentDialog.html(jqXHR.responseText);
     contentDialog.dialog({
           title : 'Erreur',
           modal : true,
           zIndex: 8888,
           resizable: false,
           close: function(event, ui) {
             $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
           },
           buttons:{"OK": function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");}}
     });

 },...
```

Comment: undertermined is a typo for untermined (infinite) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `defaultStack` [**already** contains `exception Interceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
        <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
        <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

,**you are basically including TWO exception Interceptors**, the one written by you and the original one; they're probably messing up each other;

try to compose your Stack by manually inserting the Interceptors of the Default Stack except the first exception Interceptor in your configuration:

```
 <interceptor-stack name="securedStack">
   <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
        <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
            <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
            <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
   <interceptor-ref name="login" />
 </interceptor-stack>
```

NOTE: `i18n Interceptor` is already present too...

Comment: Thanks now all the java exceptions are well catched by this interceptor and my js which called the action via ajax is entering into the error: part which will show the message to the user. One question: if the error occures in freemarker template, I will also enter into this interceptor but the line response.reset(); will throw an exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException do you know why it happens?

Comment: Nope... never used Freemarker, but I don't understand what "the error occurrs in freemarker template" means :/ But since it is totally another pair of shoes, I suggest you to open a new question with the freemarker tag to get help from the right target ;)